# Sudo won't accept correct password

Tags: sudo, authentication, kubuntu

I'm having a weird problem; sudo isn't accepting my absolutely correct password on my new Kubuntu install. This happens in terminal and in graphical sudo prompts, like if you double click a .deb or something. On the other hand, if I CTRL-ALT-F2 to any other TTY it works completely fine. Similarly though login works fine, screen lock won't accept my password either, I have to hit "Switch User" before I can unlock.

This is a completely clean install; I have made no configuration changes or anything.

If I run `sudo apt update`, enter my password and have it fail then in /var/log/auth.log I see:

```
May  8 23:27:15 djrscally-Surface-Pro-7 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/5 ruser=djrscally rhost=  user=djrscally
May  8 23:27:20 djrscally-Surface-Pro-7 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
May  8 23:27:20 djrscally-Surface-Pro-7 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [djrscally]
May  8 23:27:20 djrscally-Surface-Pro-7 sudo: djrscally : 1 incorrect password attempt ; TTY=pts/5 ; PWD=/home/djrscally ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt update
```

If I log into TTY2 and run the same command my password is accepted and /var/log/auth.log tells me:

```
May  8 23:29:14 djrscally-Surface-Pro-7 sudo: djrscally : TTY=tty2 ; PWD=/home/djrscally ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt update
May  8 23:29:14 djrscally-Surface-Pro-7 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by djrscally(uid=1000)
May  8 23:29:19 djrscally-Surface-Pro-7 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do your password contain sny non-ascii characters (like accented charscters)? Could you change (temporarilly) to a simpler password like `abcdef` and try  again?

Comment: @IsaaC I changed temporarily to a simpler password and then changed back. This had the effect of fixing the problem _for that boot_. When I rebooted, not even the login screen would take my password and I had to drop to recovery mode to repeat that exercise, at which point it worked (as in, back to the original problem) again

Comment: (1) You didn't answer the question: Does your password have any non-ASCII character?

Comment: (2)  Change your password to something **simple** and pure ASCII like DanScally624151. Then, reboot a couple of times, try your new password anywhere that was failing before and tell us what you've got with your **new** password.

Comment: (3) Changing your password for five minutes and changing it back is not what was meant. If you keep using the same input, you should expect the same result. Doh!

Comment: @user232326 Your demeaning to is unnecessary and not welcome.